# False statement returns an empty array

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to write a code where if there a duplicate numbers it returns true and if there isn't duplicates it returns false.  I get the duplicates to show up but I want it to return the word false if there aren't duplicates.  Here is the code what am I missing.

```
var numbers= [14, 50, 27, 52,  41, 5, 9, 25, 10, 6];

var uniqueArray = numbers.map((number) => {
return {count:1, number: number}
})
.reduce((a, b) => {
a[b.number] = (a[b.number] || 0) + b.count
return a
}, {})

var duplicate = Object.keys(uniqueArray ).filter((a) => uniqueArray [a] > 1)

//console.log(duplicate)

function hasDuplicates(){
  if (duplicate = true) {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: `duplicate = true` assigns the value of `true` to the variable `duplicate`

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasDuplicates(){ if (duplicate = true) { return true } }
```

The statement

```
duplicate = true
```

means "assign the variable `duplicate` the value `true` and return `true`.  That's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I get an empty array if there's no duplicate
so I would rewrite hasDuplicates function to this

```
function hasDuplicates(){
  return duplicate.length === 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.from(new Set(array)) to create unique array, then compare length of two array. If unique array has less element, it's the case of duplicate!

```
var numbers= [14, 50, 27, 52,  41, 5, 9, 25, 10, 6];
//console.log(numbers);
var uniqueArrays = Array.from(new Set(numbers));
if (uniqueArrays.length < numbers.length)
    console.log('Has duplicate!');
else
    console.log('No duplicate!');
```

Comment: Since it seems all we want is to check if there are duplicates, no need for Array.from, check directly against the `size` of this Set.

Comment: Using `Set` is also very expensive. I've included `Set` in the JS Perf if you care to see how they all perform.

Comment: Expensive = Worth!? Can you say somethings about JS Perf? Should use it in what cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this by using  `Array#some`,  `Array#every` or `Array#filter`.

[JS Perf](https://jsperf.com/array-filter-vs-some-vs-every-vs-set)

If you don't care about the actual duplicate values

Using `Array#some`

```js
const numbers = [14, 50, 27, 52, 25, 41, 5, 9, 25, 10, 25, 6];

const hasDuplicates = numbers.some((number, index, a) => numbers.indexOf(number) !== index);

console.log(hasDuplicates);
```

Using `Array#every`

```js
var numbers = [14, 50, 27, 52, 25, 41, 5, 9, 25, 10, 25, 6];

var hasDuplicates = !numbers.every((number, index) => numbers.indexOf(number) === index);

console.log(hasDuplicates);
```

Using `Array#filter`

```js
const numbers = [14, 50, 27, 52, 25, 41, 5, 9, 25, 10, 25, 6];
const uniques = numbers.filter((number, index) => numbers.indexOf(number) === index);
const hasDuplicates = numbers.length !== uniques.length;

console.log(uniques, hasDuplicates);
```

If you do care

```js
const numbers = [14, 50, 27, 52, 25, 41, 5, 9, 25, 10, 25, 6];

const duplicates = [];

const uniques = numbers.filter((number, index) => {
  return numbers.indexOf(number) === index || !duplicates.includes(number) && duplicates.push(number) && false;
});

function hasDuplicates(){
  return !!duplicates.length;
}

console.log(duplicates, uniques, hasDuplicates());
```

Comment: The first example would even win a few runs with `Array#some` instead of `#filter`.

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer to include using `.some` as the preferred choice but examples of `.filter` and `.every` with a JS Perf test.

Answer (score -1):

```
function hasDuplicates() {
  return duplicate ? 'true' : 'false';
}

var numbers= [14, 50, 27, 52,  41, 5, 9, 25, 10, 6];
var unique = {};
numbers.forEach( n => { unique[n] = 1; } );
var duplicate = numbers.length != unique.length;
```